# Looking for a textarea resize plugin similar to facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

When you're typing a comment in facebook, the comment textarea automatically resizes as you type. If you hit enter, it posts the comment, and if you hit ctrl + enter, it goes to the next line while resizing.

I'm looking for a javascript / jquery plugin that achieves the same thing.

- Resizes textareas smoothly while you type, like facebook, works in all new browsers
- Is able to be called dynamically, e.g if a new textarea is added via javascript, its able to be called right after and assigned to that textarea.
- Has an option/feature to have enter's ignored and call a callback function instead for posting what the user has typed when he hits enter.
- Has an option/feature to be pushed to the new line when ctrl + enter is pressed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if any such plugin already exists but if you don't find one you can make your own. I came up with this real quick, maybye you can use it as a starting template (by no means is it perfect or does everything you need):

http://jsfiddle.net/NfWAn/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function($) {
                $.fn.smartText = function(options) {

                    var $this = $(this);

                    var defaults = {
                        size_interval : 15
                    };

                    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

                    $('body').append('<div id="checkValHeight" style="display:none; word-wrap:break-word"></div>');
                    var checkValHeight = $('#checkValHeight');

                    $this.each(function() {
                        $this.addClass('smartText');
                    });

                    $('textarea.smartText').live('keyup paste', function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var cur_height = $this.height();

                        checkValHeight
                            .css({
                                'width': $this.width()
                            })
                            .html($this.val());

                        if(checkValHeight.height() > cur_height) {
                            $this.css({
                                'height': (cur_height + settings.size_interval) + 'px'
                            });
                        }

                        checkValHeight.empty();
                    });

                    return $this;
                }
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <script>
            $(function() {

                $('textarea').smartText({
                    size_interval: 30
                });

                $('#addTextArea').click(function() {
                    $('body').append('<textarea class="smartText"></textarea>');
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" id="addTextArea">Add Textarea [+]</a><br />

        <textarea></textarea>
        <textarea></textarea>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, it works, but seems a bit buggy. 1) If you set the event to keypress rather than keyup, then sometimes as you're typing, you haven't reached the end of the line, you're halfway on the last line when it jumps. Might be because I'm pressing and holding the key and so html() has some old value and not the new one.. 2) Sometimes you move to the next line and get a scrollbar, then have to type a bit more before the scrollbar goes away. Any ideas?

Comment: @ClickUpvote Well for #2 you can fix with css `textarea.smartText { overflow: hidden; }`. For #1 if you are pressing and holding the same key then it will wait until you let go to insert the text into the hidden div to calculate the value text's height. So it won't be updating the textarea's height in real time. In any case I agree the entire script is quite buggy, I spent about 10 min on it :) You should improve it and perhaps even release it as a plugin if you do.

Comment: Thanks for #2 :). If you change the event from keyup to keypress, then it does update it in real time, however for some lines it expands when you're halfway in a line.. I think you might be better able to fix that particular bug than me